# how can i set developer mode in magento2?

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I installed magento2 on my localhost and trying to create simple theme but I have a problem with setting developer mode 
Please, can anyone help me to set developer mode in magento2 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow @Pawan or @vadym Answer

Try this,

**`sudo php bin/magento`**

it will list out all command in Magento 2

```
sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enable developer mode from the cli

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```